# Rearrange an array such that arr[i] = i

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

```
Input : arr = {-1, -1, 6, 1, 9, 3, 2, -1, 4, -1}
Output : [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 6, -1, -1, 9]

Input : arr = {19, 7, 0, 3, 18, 15, 12, 6, 1, 8,
              11, 10, 9, 5, 13, 16, 2, 14, 17, 4}
Output : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
         11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

**Approach**
1. Nav­i­gate the array.

2. Check if a[i] = -1, if yes then ignore it.
3. If a[i] != -1, Check if element a[i] is at its cor­rect posi­tion (i=A[i]). If yes then ignore it.
4. If a[i] != -1 and ele­ment a[i] is not at its cor­rect posi­tion (i!=A[i]) then place it to its correct posi­tion, but there are two conditions:

   (i).Either A[i] is vacant, means A[i] = -1, then just put A[i] = i .

   (ii).OR A[i] is not vacant, means A[i] = x, then int y=x put A[i] = i. Now, we need to place y to its cor­rect place, so repeat from step 3.

**What would be the time complexity of below solution?**

```
public static int[] fix(int[] A) {
    for (int i = 0, x = A[i]; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (x == -1 || x == i)
            continue;

        // check if desired place is not vacant
        while (A[x] != -1 && A[x] != x) {
            int y = A[x];   // store the value from desired place
            A[x] = x;       // place the x to its correct position
            x = y;          // now y will become x, now search the place for x
        }

        A[x] = x;           // place the x to its correct position

        // check if while loop hasn't set the correct value at A[i]
        if (A[i] != i)
            A[i] = -1;      // if not then put -1 at the vacated place
    }

    return A;
}
```

Comment: Is your code working fine?

Comment: How is your first output valid? arr[0] = -1  in the first example. For arr[i] = i all you have to do is loop though the array and check if it contains all elements from i to size(arr). You might have to handle duplicates as well

Comment: Your code will work, provided that there are no duplicates and all of the values non-vacant values correspond to locations in the array. But the way this works is that you tell us what you think the complexity is, and why. And we'll help you reach the right answer.

Comment: The complexity should be 0(n)

Comment: That last edit by @oleg was completely gratuitous. The original code was a little spread out, true, but it was clear, and more correctly reflected the OP's experience level and coding style. The new code is unnecessarily terse and does nothing to aid in understanding.

Comment: The way to determine the complexity is to analyze your algorithm by hand with an array of 4 items. Using pencil and paper, write down the original array. Then start "executing" the program, writing down each change to the array. Notice how the array changes as the algorithm progresses. Notice how many iterations the inner loop makes with each iteration of the outer loop. Do the same exercise with an array of 8 items. Did it take twice as many steps? Four times as many? What does the increase in number of steps tell you about the complexity?

Answer (score 1):

I can offer you two algorithms.

**First one:** using extra array, time complexity is `O(n)`, with `O(n)` additional memory

```
public static int[] fix(int[] arr) {
    int[] res = new int[arr.length];

    Arrays.fill(res, -1);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] != -1)
            res[arr[i]] = arr[i];

    return res;
}
```

**Second one:** in place, time complexity is `O(n^2)` in worst case and `O(n)` in average case, without additional memory

```
public static int[] fix(int[] arr) {
    int i;

    while ((i = findIncorrectPosition(arr)) >= 0) {
        while (arr[i] != -1 && arr[i] != i) {
            swap(arr, i, arr[i]);
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

...plus two private support methods:

```
private static int findIncorrectPosition(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] != -1 && arr[i] != i)
            return i;
    return -1;
}

private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: I have already implemented 5 methods for this problem.
What I want to know is just complexity for above solution.
Could you please help me in that

Comment: @SanjeevGuglani It is `O(n)` in case you do not have duplication in this array.

Answer (score 0):

f(n) = O(n) using swapping methodology #Swift

```
for i in stride(from: 0, to: array.count, by: 1){
      if(array[i] >= 0 && array[i] != i){
        let ele = array[array[i]]
        array[array[i]] = array[i]
        array[i] = ele
       
      }
    }
    
    for k in stride(from: 0, to: array.count, by:1 ){
      print("  ",array[k])
    }
```